# Looping nested arrays in jQuery with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, nested

I have a JSON file that I am working with in AJAX and jQuery, it has the following data structure.

```
    {
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "2020-09",
      "name": "September 2020",
      "days": [
        {
          "date": "2020-09-19",
          "number": "19",
          "day": "Wed"
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-09-21",
          "number": "21",
          "day": "Fri"
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-09-24",
          "number": "24",
          "day": "Tues"
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-09-30",
          "number": "30",
          "day": "Sun"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-10",
      "name": "October 2020",
      "days": [
        {
          "date": "2020-10-24",
          "number": "24",
          "day": "Tues"
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-10-30",
          "number": "30",
          "day": "Wed"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to display a month and then the corresponding dates nested in that month object.

```
success: (response) => {
  $("#date-time-picker").show();

  response.data.forEach((month) => {
    console.log(month.name);
    $("#date-select-container").append(
      '<p class="py-15 font-small__14 m-0">' +
        month.name +
        '</p><div class="d-flex flex-wrap date-picker justify-content-center light-blue-border--bottom pb-5 w-100"></div>'
    );
    month.days.forEach((days) => {
      let dateSelectHtml =
        '<label class="mb-0"><input type="radio" name="date" class="card-input-element" value="' +
        days.date +
        '" /><div class="card card-input light-blue-border px-10 py-20"><h2>' +
        days.number +
        '</h2><p class="booking-info__standard-color m-0">' +
        days.day +
        "</p></div></label>";
      $(".date-picker").append(dateSelectHtml);
    });
  });
},
```

This is the result I get when running this as it is. As you can see it iterates over all the nested days in the first month object but then only iterates over the correct 2 days in the second month object.
[image: Image of front end]

Comment: `$(".date-picker")` selects _all_ elements with that class. So in your case the one for September and October. `.append()` will then add `dateSelectHtml` to all elements in the collection, hence "September" and "October". You have to find a way to only reference the `.date-picker` you've added for the current month.

Comment: I was thinking to dynamically add an id that corresponds to the date property of the object but not sure even then how it would work? I'm not sure how the children know who their respective parent is.

Comment: You're adding them sequentially. So one way would be to only select the `:last`. Or store the `.date-picker` element in an extra jQuery object, append the days onto that and then add the `.date-picker` element, ...

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

The issue for those who come across this question and have the same issue was:

on the second loop I was not identifying the parent loop correctly.

```
          response.data.forEach((month) => {
        $("#date-select-container").append(
          '<p class="py-15 font-small__14 m-0">' +
            month.name +
            '</p><div class="d-flex flex-wrap date-picker justify-content-center light-blue-border--bottom pb-5 w-100" id="month-' +
            month.date + // Here I have added the month.date as an ID for the child to identify it's parent in the next loop
            '"></div>'
        );
        if (month.days.length) {
          month.days.forEach((days) => {
            let dateSelectHtml =
              '<label class="mb-0"><input type="radio" name="date" class="card-input-element" value="' +
              days.date +
              '" /><div class="card card-input booking-info__standard-color light-blue-border px-20 m-10 py-20"><h2>' +
              days.number +
              '</h2><p class="booking-info__standard-color m-0">' +
              days.day +
              "</p></div></label>";
            $("#month-" + month.date).append(dateSelectHtml); // And then I am identifying that here to append to the correct ID.
          });
        } else {
          let noDays =
            "<p>Unfortunately there are no days available for this month</p>";
          $("#month-" + month.date).append(noDays);
        }
      });
```